# Cannot import Avro into a Gradle project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, avro

I have a Gradle project in my IntelliJ, I followed this [tutorial](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro) in my build.gradle[image: build.gradle], but IntelliJ doesn't auto pop up Avro as an option:
[image: Avro not imported]

And when I try to manually add this import [image: line], it doesn't auto complete Avro as an option either.

Actually, I searched extensively online and tried different approaches, but still no luck, any ideas please?

P.S. I'm open to any options/plugins as long as it can make Avro work in my Gradle project.
Thanks a lot!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are already done with refreshing dependencies and the problem is still there.
So try adding dependency `compile group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro-tools', version: '1.7.0'`
 instead of adding it from classpath.
You can also refer to [this](https://github.com/commercehub-oss/gradle-avro-plugin) plugin.